# javax.inject imports missing in IntelliJ for Micronaut Kotlin project

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, micronaut

I wanted to get started with Micronaut using Kotlin in IntelliJ. I can setup [this exmaple project from github](https://github.com/micronaut-guides/micronaut-cache-kotlin). Running the project with gradle works just fine. Still IntelliJ will not let me import any annotation from `javax.inject`. The editor will always display `import javax.inject.Singleton` as compilation error (e.g. red font). Mouse over displays

> Unresolved reference: Singleton

Browsing *External Libraries* in the project tree shows a dependency `javax.inject:javax.inject:1` that should contain said annotations but it is displayed as empty folder.

Since IntelliJ is using gradle for building the build works without compilation error. As mentioned in the docs: annotation processing is enabled in IntelliJ.

Am I missing something or is this broken in IntelliJ (Build #IU-202.6397.94, built on July 27, 2020, Kotlin plugin 1.4.0)

Comment: which JDK are you running?

Comment: I tried with Corretto 8 and 11

Comment: Are you using maven? If so try to reimport your project or do a mvn clean install

Comment: Do it with JDK 8. I believe they revamped the whole Javax namespace from Java 9

Comment: I am using gradle (as said above) and also the example project is using gradle. I did *Reload all gradle projects* several times by now. I even invalidated IntelliJ caches. Nothing helps. Gradle by itself works and and the application starts.

Comment: "Do it with JDK 8." - That is unlikely to make a difference with respect to this problem.  The issue is likely that the classpath configured in the IDE is incorrect.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I am not so sure about that. Any other class that is defined as dependency is loaded correctly. Only `javax.inject` is an empty jar.

Comment: " I am not so sure about that." - It is definitely not the case that you have to use Java 8.  The fact that your build works from Gradle means that the classes are available.  The problem is how the IDE project is configured.  If you want some help, submit the free consultation form at https://objectcomputing.com/products/micronaut and I will jump on a screen share with you and we will work it out.

Comment: See if http://jeffscreencasts.s3.amazonaws.com/javax_java11.mp4 is helpful.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thanks for the video, everything looks the same configuration wise. I tried on my Win10 machine (originally I was using Ubuntu) and there everything is fine. For the most part both installations have the same configuration (apart from the OS, obviously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Micronaut 3.0, micronaut Gradle plugin adds new `jakarta.inejct` artifact automatically. No need add it explicitly.

Try to build the project by command line(`./gradlew  build`) in Intellij IDEA *terminal* windows, then refresh the project in the Gradle pane.

Check my example to demo [Kotlin and Kotlin Coroutines](https://github.com/hantsy/micronaut-sandbox).

Answer (score 2):

[Micronaut 3 M2 Released](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE0dn.png)

This should answer your question. Adding this below to dependencies should help if you prefer using javax

```
implementation("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")
```